# Php-cgi cmd.exe NAME NOT FOUND Desired Access:

Tags: php, iis-7, exec, fastcgi, cmd

I can't seems to get php exec(), system()... Etc, running under IIS 7 and Windows 2008. The commands return a warning message like "unable to fork" and procmon from sysinternals noted the following.

4:27:09.8102497 PM php-cgi.exe 3520 CreateFile C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\cmd.exe NAME NOT FOUND Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a.

I've given the impersonated user full access to cmd.exe under system32 and wow64. I've even given the apppool permissions to cmd.exe. The message above seems to indicate that php is looking for cmd.exe in the wrong path but the path settings on this machine contain the system folders. Totally stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this and just shut IIS down in favour of Apache. Wasted almost 3 days fighting this issue only to resolve it in a few hours with Apache. Sigh.